# How do I initialize a Scala map with more than 4 initial elements in Java?

Tags: java, scala, map

For 4 or fewer elements, something like this works (or at least compiles):

```
import scala.collection.immutable.Map;

Map<String,String> HAI_MAP = new Map4<>("Hello", "World",
                                        "Happy", "Birthday",
                                        "Merry", "XMas",
                                        "Bye", "For Now");
```

For a 5th element I *could* do this:

```
Map<String,String> b = HAI_MAP.$plus(new Tuple2<>("Later", "Aligator"));
```

But I want to know how to initialize an immutable map with 5 or more elements and I'm flailing in Type-hell.

## Partial Solution

I thought I'd figure this out quickly by compiling what I wanted in Scala, then decompiling the resultant class files.  Here's the scala:

```
object JavaMapTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val HAI_MAP = Map(("Hello", "World"),
                      ("Happy", "Birthday"),
                      ("Merry", "XMas"),
                      ("Bye", "For Now"),
                      ("Later", "Aligator"))
    println("My map is: " + HAI_MAP)
  }
}
```

But the [decompiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/) gave me something that has two periods in a row and thus won't compile (I don't think this is valid Java):

```
scala.collection.immutable.Map HAI_MAP =
        (scala.collection.immutable.Map) 
        scala.Predef..MODULE$.Map().apply(scala.Predef..MODULE$.wrapRefArray(
                scala.Predef.wrapRefArray(
                        (Object[])new Tuple2[] {
                                new Tuple2("Hello", "World"),
                                new Tuple2("Happy", "Birthday"),
                                new Tuple2("Merry", "XMas"),
                                new Tuple2("Bye", "For Now"),
                                new Tuple2("Later", "Aligator") }));
```

I'm really baffled by the two periods in this:

```
scala.Predef..MODULE$
```

I asked about it on `#java` on Freenode and they said the `..` looked like a decompiler bug.  It doesn't seem to want to compile, so I think they are probably right.  I'm running into it when I try to browse interfaces in IntelliJ and am just generally lost.

Based on my experimentation, the following is valid:

```
Tuple2[] x = new Tuple2[] { new Tuple2<String,String>("Hello", "World"),
                            new Tuple2<String,String>("Happy", "Birthday"),
                            new Tuple2<String,String>("Merry", "XMas"),
                            new Tuple2<String,String>("Bye", "For Now"),
                            new Tuple2<String,String>("Later", "Aligator") };

scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray<Tuple2> y = scala.Predef.wrapRefArray(x);
```

There is even a `WrappedArray.toMap()` method but the types of the signature are complicated and I'm running into the double-period problem there too when I try to research the interfaces from Java.

Comment: WHy don't you just create a "regular" map and then copy that map? I guess scala's immutable map has such a constructor?

Comment: @fge Good thought.  There is a MapBuilder, but you have to pass an empty collection, and then the signature of the "add-all" method is complicated: `scala.collection.generic.Growable<scala.Tuple2<A,B>> $plus$plus$eq(scala.collection.TraversableOnce<scala.Tuple2<A,B>> xs)`.  I could figure out how to make a Growable and TraversableOnce and call a method named `$plus$plus$eq` from Java, which IntelliJ did NOT like.  Maybe I'll try that route again, but it seemed to me that there must be an easier way.

Comment: Did you look at scala.collection.JavaConversions.mapAsScalaMap ?  http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConversions$

Comment: @Ruben - another good thought, but I'm specifically looking for an immutable collection and JavaConversions try to be true to the Java and use mutable collections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The decompiler probably has problems in decompiling class names correctly that contain a `$` symbol. The symbol you are searching for is named `Predef$`:

```
import scala.Predef;
import scala.Predef$;
import scala.Tuple2;
import scala.collection.immutable.Map;
import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray;

public class T {
  @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
  public static void main(final String... args) {
    final Tuple2[] ts = { new Tuple2("a", "b") };
    final WrappedArray wa = Predef.wrapRefArray(ts);
    final Map<String, String> map = Predef$.MODULE$.Map().apply(wa);
    System.out.println(map);
  }
}
```

Thus, I emphasize not to use a decompiler but the internal representation of the AST in scalac:

```
$ scala -print -e 'Map(("a", "b"))'
...
scala.this.Predef.Map().apply(
  scala.this.Predef.wrapRefArray(
    Array[Tuple2]{new Tuple2("a", "b")}.$asInstanceOf[Array[Object]]()));
...
```

If you are interested in more information about how to work with the output of scalac then take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350528/how-to-work-with-javap-for-scala-java-interoperability) and its answers.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
java.util.Map<String, String> javaMap = new java.util.HashMap<String, String>();
javaMap.put("Hello", "World");
javaMap.put("Happy", "Birthday");
javaMap.put("Merry", "XMas");
javaMap.put("Bye", "For Now");
javaMap.put("Later", "Aligator");

scala.collection.Map<String, String> scalaMap = scala.collection.JavaConversions$.MODULE$.asMap(javaMap);
System.out.println(scalaMap);
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not reading this correctly, but I think the resultant map is mutable in your example, no?  I'm specifically looking for an immutable map.